# How to ensure that users are enrolled in MFA

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a large number of users to set up that all need to access to the data warehouse at the same time. A security requirement for our company is that all users must be set up with multi-factor authentication. From what I have read, users must enroll themselves in MFA, so  how can we ensure that users are enrolled before they can access the data ? Is there any best practice surrounding this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can list out all the users which have ext_authn_duo=false by running:

```
show users
```

This will be the easiest way to get the list and also have those users enroll for DUO.

Expanding on this further, you can build a snowsight (New UI) dashboard and use the following Stored procedure to get the details which can be run using Tasks as detailed here:

```
/** This is the Stored procedure**/

    create or replace procedure MFA_USERS()
returns string
language javascript
Execute as CALLER
as
$$

var qry = ` show users `;
var qry_rslt = snowflake.execute({sqlText: qry});
var qry_id= qry_rslt.getQueryId();

var qry2 = ` select * from table(result_scan('${qry_id}')) `;
rs = snowflake.execute({sqlText: qry2});

var out = "";
var i = 0;

while (rs.next()) {
    if (i++ > 0) out += ",";
    out += rs.getColumnValue(1);
}

return out;

$$;
  


  /** Create a task that calls the stored procedure every hour**/
    create task my_copy_task
      warehouse = mywh
      schedule = '60 minute'
    as
      call MFA_USERS();
```

This will give only the list of those users in a list for review from dashboard and avoid the need to run the query manually.

Comment: That gives you ALL users.  How do you restrict to just those without MFA?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, users must enroll themself into MFA.

One way to ensure that they are not able to access any data in snowflake before this enrollment is using the [Role Based Access Control](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html) approach.
As your user is created, do not grant him any role besides the **PUBLIC** role which is the default role and should not have any access to real data.

Then you can automate a process that will control using `SHOW USERS` command which users activated their MFA access (**ext_authn_duo** and **ext_authn_uid** columns). Then you can grant an access role to data to this confirmed users.

One other approach could be to let a short time period for recent users to enroll into MFA, automate check and disable their access to Snowflake if not fulfilled using `ALTER USER my_user SET disabled = true`.

Answer (score 1):

I asked Snowflake support about this and they said that easiest would be to use federated authentication and enforce the requirements on the IdP level.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-overview